# How to register touches while another finger is held down

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

On a WP7 device I have a canvas.  When the user touches anywhere on the canvas an image is displayed at that position.

I want to add a feature where if a user touches and holds the screen with one finger and then touches the screen in another place with a different finger an image is also displayed.  So basically I want to be able capture and respond to the second touch in the simplest possible way.  Any ideas?

Comment: i got a win7 phone, n its only capable of handing 1 finger (non multi touch), if i touch a second finger the "cursor" goes to the middle of the two lol its no iphone

Comment: Weird I thought they had to handle multitouch as part of the base specs.  Mine handles pinching etc no problems

Comment: Oh man, every WP7 supports a minimum of FOUR multitouch points, thats fact!

Comment: in XNA you can access all four. In silverlight you're limited to 2 simultanious ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the GestureService? The Pinch* events let you handle two simultanious touches.

See [example](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/01/20/building-touch-interfaces-for-windows-phones-part-4.aspx).

Comment: I'm assuming silverlight. The solution for xna is different.

Comment: Pinch completed gave me exactly what i wanted.  I have the left mouse down event on canvas and then the pinch complete handles the 2nd touch.  Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

what you need is just the GestureListener which lies in the Microsoft.Phone.Controls namespace, which can handle a couple gestures like

- Flick
- Pinch
- Drag
- Swipe
- etc.

You can use it like so

```
var gestureListener = GestureService.GetGestureListener(myCanvas);

//registering the Events
gestureListener.PinchStarted += new EventHandler<PinchStartedGestureEventArgs>(PinchStartedHandler);
gestureListener.PinchDelta += new EventHandler<PinchGestureEventArgs>(PinchDeltaHandler);
gestureListener.PinchCompleted += new EventHandler<PinchGestureEventArgs>(PinchCompletedHandler);
```

In the approriate Hanler-Methods you do your rotate- and scale- transformations.

Comment: Sorry that I can't mark your answer as correct as well because it is.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you are clearly in Silverlight, this post shows you how to implement multitouch for yourself - http://mine.tuxfamily.org/?p=111

Register for touches

```
 Touch.FrameReported += new TouchFrameEventHandler(Touch_FrameReported);
```

Then handle those touches:

```
 void Touch_FrameReported(object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)
 {
        // if there are more than one finger on screen
        if (e.GetTouchPoints(myCanvas).Count == 2)
        {
            TouchPointCollection tpc = e.GetTouchPoints(myCanvas);
            // use tpc[0].Position
            // use tpc[1].Position
        }
 }
```

Alternatively, if you want to use ready-build Gestures, then consider using the latest Silverlight Toolkit - see this blog post for information - http://3water.wordpress.com/2011/03/09/wp7-gesture-recognition-2/